# How do I stop windows from trashing my SSD?

Tags: windows-10

There are three processes that are really destroying my SSD:

- System
- ShadowPlay
- GlassWire

I guess I'm getting rid of glasswire because they can't seem to get their logging under control (logging >10GB per day is just way too much, and I'm not even torrenting or anything remotely close)

I already moved ShadowPlays temp files to a RAM disk

But the system process is killing me. In just 11 minutes, Windows logged over 350 MB of data just for the defender api logger (whatever that is good for), if I extrapolate that it's going to be 1.9GB per hour, that's insane.

[Windows writing infinity^2 defender logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmanL.png)

Is there a way to stop Windows from doing that? I've looked around the interwebs but I can't find something that's specific to `EtwRTDefenderApiLogger.etl`.

Edited: I just let it log some more and it just keeps growing significantly:

[more logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2UW0.png)

Comment: Why is your system creating trace log files for defender? [Check](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/132684-etwrtdefenderapilogger-etl.html) there to see if trace is on

Comment: @Ramhound it's literally what I'm trying to find out. It says disabled, but when I try to save it it always says access denied (scroll to the bottom of the page that you linked me). It seems to "have accepted" that I disabled it, even though I could never press OK. Windows things. I'm not sure this will solve the issue, though.